# Why flatMap doesn't remove empty arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, flatmap

I have a flatMap function that fetch and return data for each item in array. It also returns an empty array if item doesn't have certain informations. Since I'm using flatMap I was expecting that it will remove all the empty arrays, but the finished array still have them included.

Function:

```
 Promise.all(
        array.flatMap(async (item) => {
        const fetchedData = await fetch(`${item.url}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => data.stats.length ? data : null);
        return fetchedData ? { ...fetchedData } : [];
    })).then(data => console.log(data));
```

Also when I log the data using *console.log(data.flat())* instead of *console.log(data)* all the empty arrays are removed, but it would require iterating through array one more time. Any ideas why flatMap isn't doing it by itself?

Comment: `fetchedData ? { ...fetchedData } : []` this looks a bit weird, you're returning either an object or an array depending on `fetchedData`, is that expected?

Comment: I think so, that's the syntax of flatMap. Works the same with numbers where you return either a number or empty array and that empty array is being removed.

Comment: if you're calling `flat()` on the already `flatMap`ed array you are flattening one more level which would explain the removal of empty arrays

Comment: @pilchard yeah but that's what `flatMap` was supposed to do, wasn't it?

Comment: Only by one level, per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) `...and then flattening the result by one level. It is identical to a map() followed by a flat() of depth 1, but slightly more efficient than calling those two methods separately.`

Answer (score 4):

It's because your callback inside of `flatMap` is an `async` function, so it always returns a Promise no matter what. Let's say `array` has two items, the first which will have `fetchedData` and the second which will not, here's an example of what will happen:

`array` is: `[item1, item2]`

After the map part of `flatMap` you get `[Promise(pending), Promise(pending)]`  (note that the mapping is instantaneous, it doesn't wait for the async functions to complete, it just gets the promise returned from them).

After the flattening part you get `[Promise(pending), Promise(pending)]` (note that this is the same as the above line - promises can't be flattened.).

Promise.all.then() waits for each promise to resolve and passes the result as `data` which you log and is `[someObject, emptyArray]`.

Comment: is there some way to get this to resolve as expected? How do we get the async to resolve before returning to the flatMap?